# Are there any winforms spinner like controls for adjusting floating point values?

Tags: .net, winforms, floating-point, spinner

I have .NET app with a floating point value that I want to adjust up and down by a user adjustable increment with something like a [spinner control](http://kendsnyder.com/sandbox/Spinner/). Before I go off and build my own, does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 6):

Like a NumericUpDown?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx

Comment: It however works with the Decimal type though... so you may need to cast-recast from Float. Other than should work...

Comment: A pair of those might work, one to controle the value and one to control the Increment.

Comment: The NumericUpDown control has an Increment property and a DecimalPlaces property that you may need to let the users alter somehow

Answer (score 2):

[DevExpress](http://devexpress.com) have such a [SpinEdit](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/editors/SpinEdit.xml) component in their suite